# I have an id encrypted from c#. How can i decrypt this id on iphone

Tags: c#, iphone, encryption

I have used this code to encrypt an ID in C#. I now need to decrypt the ID on an iphone. How can I implent the same decryption there?

```
public class Cryptographer
{

    private static byte[] iv ={(byte)24,(byte)51,(byte)32,(byte)53,
    (byte)54,(byte)55,(byte)64,(byte)95,
    (byte)121,(byte)53,(byte)71,(byte)60,
    (byte)38,(byte)154,(byte)81,(byte)11};

    private static byte[] keys ={(byte)2,(byte)13,(byte)79,(byte)233,
    (byte)121,(byte)53,(byte)71,(byte)60,
    (byte)7,(byte)98,(byte)183,(byte)21,
    (byte)38,(byte)154,(byte)81,(byte)11};

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Cryptographer()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    internal static string GetDecryptedConnectionString()
    {
        string sResult;
        sResult = Cryptographer.DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LuckyEyeConnStr"].ToString(), "M1n0t3urK1nG");
        return sResult;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Description: Generates Random Password</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="PasswordLength">Length of The Password</param>
    /// <returns>String Includes Password</returns>
    internal static string CreateRandomPassword(int PasswordLength)
    {
        System.String _allowedChars = "bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ23456789";
        Byte[] randomBytes = new Byte[PasswordLength];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
        char[] chars = new char[PasswordLength];
        int allowedCharCount = _allowedChars.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < PasswordLength; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = _allowedChars[(int)randomBytes[i] % allowedCharCount];
        }

        return new string(chars);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Description: Generates Salt Which  Will Be Used To Generate Hash.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal static string CreateSalt(int size)
    {
        // Generate a cryptographic random number using the cryptographic
        // service provider
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] buff = new byte[size];
        rng.GetBytes(buff);
        // Return a Base64 string representation of the random number
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Description: Generates Passsword Hash.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pwd">Password To Be Hashed.</param>
    /// <param name="salt">SaltString Which Will Be Used In Hashing.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string CreatePasswordHash(string pwd, string salt)
    {
        string saltAndPwd = String.Concat(pwd, salt);
        string hashedPwd =
            FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(
            saltAndPwd, "SHA1");
        return hashedPwd;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Description: Encrypts String By Using Base String(Symmetric Encryption)</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="InputText">String Which Will Be Encrypted.</param>
    /// <param name="Password">Base String Which Will Be Used In Encryption. (Key To Encrypt, Decrypt)</param>
    /// <returns>Encrypted String</returns>
    public static string EncryptString(string InputText, string Password)
    {
        // We are now going to create an instance of the 
        // Rihndael class.  

        RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();

        // First we need to turn the input strings into a byte array.

        byte[] PlainText = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(InputText);

        // We are using salt to make it harder to guess our key
        // using a dictionary attack.

        byte[] Salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password.Length.ToString());

        // The (Secret Key) will be generated from the specified 
        // password and salt.

        PasswordDeriveBytes SecretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, Salt);


        // Create a encryptor from the existing SecretKey bytes.
        // We use 32 bytes for the secret key 
        // (the default Rijndael key length is 256 bit = 32 bytes) and
        // then 16 bytes for the IV (initialization vector),
        // (the default Rijndael IV length is 128 bit = 16 bytes)

        ICryptoTransform Encryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(32), SecretKey.GetBytes(16));


        // Create a MemoryStream that is going to hold the encrypted bytes 

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();


        // Create a CryptoStream through which we are going to be processing our data. 
        // CryptoStreamMode.Write means that we are going to be writing data 
        // to the stream and the output will be written in the MemoryStream
        // we have provided. (always use write mode for encryption)

        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        // Start the encryption process.

        cryptoStream.Write(PlainText, 0, PlainText.Length);

        // Finish encrypting.

        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Convert our encrypted data from a memoryStream into a byte array.

        byte[] CipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        // Close both streams.

        memoryStream.Close();

        cryptoStream.Close();


        // Convert encrypted data into a base64-encoded string.
        // A common mistake would be to use an Encoding class for that. 
        // It does not work, because not all byte values can be
        // represented by characters. We are going to be using Base64 encoding
        // That is designed exactly for what we are trying to do. 

        string EncryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes);

        // Return encrypted string.

        return EncryptedData;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Description: Decrypts String By Using Base String(Symmetric Encryption)</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="InputText">String Which Will Be Decrypted.</param>
    /// <param name="Password">Base String Which Will Be Used In Decryption. (Key To Encrypt, Decrypt)</param>
    /// <returns>Decrypted Plain String</returns>
    public static string DecryptString(string InputText, string Password)
    {
            RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
            byte[] EncryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(InputText);
            byte[] Salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password.Length.ToString());
            PasswordDeriveBytes SecretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, Salt);
            // Create a decryptor from the existing SecretKey bytes.

            ICryptoTransform Decryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(32), SecretKey.GetBytes(16));
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(EncryptedData);

            // Create a CryptoStream. (always use Read mode for decryption).
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            // Since at this point we don't know what the size of decrypted data
            // will be, allocate the buffer long enough to hold EncryptedData;
            // DecryptedData is never longer than EncryptedData.

            byte[] PlainText = new byte[EncryptedData.Length];

            // Start decrypting.

            int DecryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(PlainText, 0, PlainText.Length);

            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();

            // Convert decrypted data into a string. 

            string DecryptedData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(PlainText, 0, DecryptedCount);
            // Return decrypted string.   

            return DecryptedData;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Description: Encrypts File By Using Base String(Symmetric Encryption)</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="FileLocation">File Location</param>
    /// <param name="FileDestination">File Destination</param>
    /// <param name="Password">Base String Which Will Be Used In Encryption. (Key To Encrypt, Decrypt)</param>
    private static void EncryptFile(string FileLocation, string FileDestination, string Password)
    {

        RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();



        // First we are going to open the file streams 

        FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(FileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(FileDestination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);



        byte[] Salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password.Length.ToString());



        PasswordDeriveBytes SecretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, Salt);



        ICryptoTransform Encryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(32), SecretKey.GetBytes(16));



        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsOut, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);



        int ByteData;

        while ((ByteData = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {

            cryptoStream.WriteByte((byte)ByteData);

        }



        cryptoStream.Close();

        fsIn.Close();

        fsOut.Close();

    }
```

Comment: give us a little more background on this question, explain what you wish to achieve in a little more detail. Then we can help you better. Also, reduce your code a little, big blocks of code aren't very helpful

Comment: Definitely one of the worst questions I've ever seen. You claim to be asking your question from your title (at least it has a sense), but you drop here lots of code and require us lots of reverse engineering work (at least you put some comments).

Comment: I almost want to give him a +1 just based on the fact he is going to encrypt ( and using the correct type of algorithm ) the application file's contents which is always nice.  The question is still horrible, sounds like a person who knows the correct thing to do but has not experience implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is to use the CommonCryptor helpers from the CommonCrypto framework. It is quite easy to work with:

```
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

...

NSMutableData* data = ... some data to encrypt in place.
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1] = ... your secret key
size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, 
                                 kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, 
                                 keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                 NULL, 
                                 [data mutableBytes], [data length], /* input */
                                 [data mutableBytes], [data length], /* output */
                                 &numBytesEncrypted);
if (result != kCCSuccess) {
   // OOPS!
}
```

There is also easy support for encrypting and decrypting in chunks, in case you have more data than can easily fit in ram.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MonoTouch to develop the iOS application.  In that case, your code would be all .net based, and decryption would be simple.